# In which Symfony event can I have access to which submit button was clicked?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to do some transformation on the submitted data based on which button on my form was clicked. Here is the scenario:

1. I have a text field named `chain` which holds the command chain.
2. I have a `command` text field that holds the last command.
3. I have two buttons on the form: `Send` and `Send chain`.

When `Send` is clicked, `chain` is set to `command`, erasing whatever was in it before. When `Send chain` is clicked, however, the contents of `command` are added to the end of `chain` after a delimiter, effectively creating a chain of commands.

I need to be able to check to see which of these two buttons was clicked so that I can set `chain` to the appropriate value.

Why am I not doing this in the controller? The problem is that I need to modify the value of `chain`. Since I cannot modify the values of an already-submitted form, I need to do this in an event, I assume. As I mentioned above, I need `chain` to either be equal to `command`, or `chain + [delimiter] + command`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you don't need an event at all. There is a built in method `isClicked()` since @2.3. Example from documentation:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ... do something

    // the save_and_add button was clicked
    if ($form->get('save_and_add')->isClicked()) {
        // probably redirect to the add page again
    }

    // redirect to the show page for the just submitted item
}
```

Link to [chapter.](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-buttons-support-in-forms)

*Update*

Normally, the code I showed can be used in event - `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` to be precise, but as you already pointed out, you can not modify form data after submission. To be honest I can't come up with perfectly working example, so I will share an idea hoping it will lead to something, or at least until someone else suggest something else.

How about you add a hidden **non** mapped field to your form. Then (assuming you are allowed to use javascript in your form) you can attach event listener on when form is submitted and based on which button was clicked you can populate that hidden field with specific value. After that you can add event listener to your FormType and read the value of this hidden field, using `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA`.

I am sorry I can not be more helpful as of now. If I came up with something I will edit my post.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I edited my question to better explain my intent. Sorry for not being clear enough the first time around.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, my problem is that when I click the `send` button, the `isClicked()` function still returns false.

Comment: Yes that is normal behaviour, since `isClicked()` shows whether the selected button **submitted** the form - therefore it will only work on `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT`. Take a look at the javascript suggestion.

Comment: Javascript is not an option. And the function returns false even in the `POST_SUBMIT` event.

Comment: That can't be right, there must be something you're doing wrong. I've tested it with two submit buttons, and the event works just as expected.

Comment: There must be something wrong with how I do it. I'll test further and let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found the solution and posted it as an answer. Hope it helps you, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I needed to do:

1. I couldn't use the `POST_submit` event because I couldn't transform the data after submission.
2. The `isClicked()` of both buttons returned `false` in other events, because the form hadn't been submitted yet.

The solution is something like this:

```
$data = $event->getData();

if (isset($data['send']) {
    // transform the values here
}
```

In other words, the only way to check if a particular button was clicked is to check to see if its name exists as an index in the array returned by `$event->getData()`.